# Using async/await inside for loop is not waiting for async method calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

My async method `getNumFruit` is not getting called for my below code

```
const fruitsToGet = ['apple', 'grape', 'pear']
const fruitBasket = {
  apple: 27, 
  grape: 0,
  pear: 14 
}
console.log("start");




async function getNumFruit(fruit) {
   console.log("iside")
  return sleep(1000).then(v => fruitBasket[fruit])
}

async function test(){
    console.log("inside test");

  for(i=0;i++;i<fruitsToGet.length){
  console.log("start2");

    const fruit = fruitsToGet[index]
    const numFruit = await getNumFruit(fruit)
    console.log(numFruit)

  }
  return "done";
}
var result = test();
console.log(result)

console.log("end!!!!!")
```

can someone help me understanding what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: Your loop is wrong it should be ```for(i = 0 ; i < fruitsToGet.length ; i++)```

Comment: also an async function always returns a promise so you will need to call `.then()` on `test()` to see the returned value

Comment: where in your code have you defined `sleep()`?

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of things wrong here:

1. Your `for` loop needs to be `for (let i = 0; i < fruitsToGet.length; i++) {`  so you both declare the loop variable and increment it in the right place.
2. Then, you need to use `i`, not `index` in your loop.
3. Then, you need to use `test().then(result => console.log(result))` to know when `test()` is actually done because it's an `async` function so it returns a promise that you have to monitor with `.then()` or `await` to know when it's done.
4. You don't show the code for the function `sleep()`.

Take a look at this fixed up code which you can run in this snippet to see the results for yourself:

```js
const fruitsToGet = ['apple', 'grape', 'pear'];

const fruitBasket = {
  apple: 27, 
  grape: 0,
  pear: 14 
};

console.log("start");

function sleep(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

function getNumFruit(fruit) {
   console.log("iside")
   return sleep(1000).then(v => fruitBasket[fruit]);
}

async function test(){
  console.log("inside test");

  for (let i = 0; i < fruitsToGet.length; i++) {
    console.log("start loop invocation", i);

    const fruit = fruitsToGet[i];
    const numFruit = await getNumFruit(fruit);
    console.log(numFruit);
  }
  return "done";
}

test().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log("end!!!!!")
});
```

When you run it, it generates this output:

```
start
inside test
start loop invocation 0
iside
27
start loop invocation 1
iside
0
start loop invocation 2
iside
14
done
end!!!!!
```

Comment: As a side note, the code is also missing `sleep()`. Probably not the original but at least the one here that is supposed to be a [mcve].

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, I just assumed it's a promise returning delay function.